# How to delete file named "-d" in unix(Mac OSX) from command line?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

I was playing with tail, head, cut and awk commands on a text file and somehow these commands created empty files with names "-d" and "-f2" (It could be due to ). Now I am not able to delete these files from command line since all commands take these as options. Of course I can delete these from Finder but I am wondering how to delete these from command line.

Comment: This would be appropriate on Unix or Superuser, but it's a duplicate.


Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `--` to separate the files from the command line arguments. That is

```
rm -- -d -f2
```

Or, you can use the full path or a relative path containing at least a `/`:

```
rm ./-d ./-f2
```